# How to properly format a tx for cardano-submit-api

Tags: cardano-submit-api

The documentation for `cardano-submit-api` specifies the following:

> Assuming `data` is a serialized transaction on the file-system.
> curl -X POST 
> --header "Content-Type: application/cbor" 
> --data-binary @data http://localhost:8101/api/submit/tx

Does anyone have any idea what this 'serialized transaction' is supposed to be? What kind of datastructure should it be...?

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the "tx.signed" signed transaction file to the cbor format like this on linux:

```
jq .cborHex tx.signed  | xxd -r -p > tx.signed.cbor
```

Comment: What are the contents of tx.signed?

Comment: tx.signed is the signed transaction (cardano-cli transaction sign command).

Comment: If you're using `cardano-cli` to build the tx anyway, then why not just use `cardano-cli transaction submit` instead of the `cardano-submit-api`?

Comment: You ask how to convert it to the cbor format to submit it to a cardano submit-api, and then you ask why you should do that? What could I answer to this? :)

Comment: More specifically I am asking what datastructure the `cardano-submit-api` takes so that I can build it without tools like `cardano-cli`. I am however interested in tangential questions like 'why would one ever use `cardano-submit-api` if they are forced to use `cardano-cli` to create the tx datastructure in the first place.

Comment: You can create and sign a transaction without cardano-cli. There are many examples or working projects on Github doing this using Javascript and the Cardano Serialization Library.